# Replace a loop to retrieve the index of the first element in an array

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a better way to search for the index of the first element using a predicate?

```
// ... this code looks a bit long to me.  Anyway to do better?
auto it = std::find_if(collection + startAt, 
                       collection + COLLECTION_SIZE, 
                       [](const char* line) { return strlen(line) <= 10; });
int idx = std::dist(collection, it); //= it - collection;
```

This is my attempt to refactor the C-style code below:

```
for (posEmptyItem = startAt; strlen(collection[posEmptyItem]) > 10; posEmptyItem++) {}
std::cout << posEmptyItem << std::endl;
```

Here a complete example of

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

#define COLLECTION_SIZE 123

int main()
{
    char* collection[COLLECTION_SIZE]{ "time11,time2,time3",
                                       "time12,time2,time3",
                                       "time13,time2,time3",
                                       "time14,time2,time3",
                                       "time15,time2,time3",
                                       "x\n", 
                                       "" };
    auto startAt = 2;
    int posEmptyItem;

    // legacy code
    for (posEmptyItem = startAt; strlen(collection[posEmptyItem]) > 10; posEmptyItem++) {}
    std::cout << posEmptyItem << std::endl;

    // replace the loop to search an index by calling to standard library
    auto it = std::find_if(collection + startAt, 
                           collection + COLLECTION_SIZE, 
                           [](const char* line) { return strlen(line) <= 10; });
    posEmptyItem = it - collection;
    std::cout << posEmptyItem << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is it that you want?

Comment: Consider using [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) instead of subtracting your iterators. It works for non-random access iterators.

Comment: Thanks for std::distance. The expression idx = it - collection looks strange to me.

Comment: If you are searching for feedback on working code, you should be posting at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: `char* collection[COLLECTION_SIZE]...` is not standard C++ and you should be receiving an error or warning from your compiler about it.  If you want a pointer to a string literal then you should be using a `const char*`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll go to codereview.stackexchange.com when I am searching feedback on working code.